# Open Source Tool to draw architecture diagram

Tags: diagram, component-diagram

I would like to draw a architectural diagram for our platform.Things I am going to represent the following physical server instances.

- Web Server - Apache (It could be many)
- Application Server - JBoss EAP ( It could be a many instances with many cluster group)
- Database Server - MySQL

I have tried with Online UML Deployment diagram tools and also some offline tools. But I dont find anything good.

Can anyone suggest me ?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example: What OS should it run on? What specific requirements do you have (support icons/pictures – included with the app and/or from own sources, linking, whatever)?

Comment: @Izzy : Sure, I will update it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to manually draw the diagram I would suggest [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/).

- Free
- Cross platform
- Lots of clipart